# How to loop through json file?

Tags: json

I have a below json file and I want to get the hostId, only if the `name` contains some specific value. I want to use shell script to achieve this.

```
{
  "items" : [ {
    "name" : "first-block-e70a2fe8fd0531ad1f87de49f03537a6",
    "type" : "STORE",
    "hostRef" : {
      "hostId" : "166219e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ce32"
    },
    "roleState" : "STARTED",
    "healthSummary" : "GOOD",

    },
  {
   "name" : "second-block-c21a1ae8dd2831cd1b87de49f98274e8",
    "type" : "STORE",
    "hostRef" : {
      "hostId" : "176429e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ad63"
    },
    "roleState" : "STARTED",
    "healthSummary" : "GOOD",
  }

  {
   "name" : "first-block-a85d2fe6fd0482ad1f54de49f45174a0",
    "type" : "STORE",
    "hostRef" : {
      "hostId" : "176429e3-ae1d-46d0-b4c7-66123a24fa82"
    },
    "roleState" : "STARTED",
    "healthSummary" : "GOOD",
  }

}
```

For example: if the name contains something with 'first-block' then I should get the hosdId as

```
166219e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ce32
176429e3-ae1d-46d0-b4c7-66123a24fa82
```

How can I iterate through the json file? What regex should I use to filter the element that contains some specific value in `name` and get the `hostid`?

Comment: You want a json parser like [jshon](http://kmkeen.com/jshon/).

Comment: Anything that will support the shell script would be fine.

Comment: probably 4 outta 7 roads will lead you to **jq** but there's a decent overview to that and a few others here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27127091/parse-json-in-shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple sample using python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import json

def print_first(data):
    for item in data["items"]:
        if item["name"].startswith("first"):
            print item["hostRef"]["hostId"]

def main(argv):
    for json_file in argv:
        with open(json_file) as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)
            print_first(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

That is with your sample data re-formatted as:

```
{
    "items" : [
        {
            "name" : "first-block-e70a2fe8fd0531ad1f87de49f03537a6",
            "type" : "STORE",
            "hostRef" : {
                "hostId" : "166219e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ce32"
            },
            "roleState" : "STARTED",
            "healthSummary" : "GOOD"

        },
        {
            "name" : "second-block-c21a1ae8dd2831cd1b87de49f98274e8",
            "type" : "STORE",
            "hostRef" : {
                "hostId" : "176429e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ad63"
            },
            "roleState" : "STARTED",
            "healthSummary" : "GOOD"
        },
        {
            "name" : "first-block-a85d2fe6fd0482ad1f54de49f45174a0",
            "type" : "STORE",
            "hostRef" : {
                "hostId" : "176429e3-ae1d-46d0-b4c7-66123a24fa82"
            },
            "roleState" : "STARTED",
            "healthSummary" : "GOOD"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use jq:

Input file:

```
{
  "items" : [
    {
      "name" : "first-block-e70a2fe8fd0531ad1f87de49f03537a6",
      "type" : "STORE",
      "hostRef" : {
        "hostId" : "166219e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ce32"
      },
      "roleState" : "STARTED",
      "healthSummary" : "GOOD"

    },
    {
      "name" : "second-block-c21a1ae8dd2831cd1b87de49f98274e8",
      "type" : "STORE",
      "hostRef" : {
        "hostId" : "176429e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ad63"
      },
      "roleState" : "STARTED",
      "healthSummary" : "GOOD"
    },

    {
      "name" : "first-block-a85d2fe6fd0482ad1f54de49f45174a0",
      "type" : "STORE",
      "hostRef" : {
        "hostId" : "176429e3-ae1d-46d0-b4c7-66123a24fa82"
      },
      "roleState" : "STARTED",
      "healthSummary" : "GOOD"
    }
  ]
}
```

command:

**Edit:** with @Runium's contribution

```
$ jq '.items[] | select( .name | startswith("first-block-"))|.hostRef.hostId' < file.json 
"e70a2fe8fd0531ad1f87de49f03537a6"
"a85d2fe6fd0482ad1f54de49f45174a0"
```

Comment: Believe that should be `jq '.items[] | select( .name | startswith("first-block-"))|.hostRef.hostId'` as in: he wants `hostId`, not hash part of `name`

Comment: @adonis, @Runium, I get the below error when i try this
`./test.sh: line 1: jq: command not found`

Comment: You should install `jq`. The way to do this depends on your distro.

Answer (score 1):

As @Theophrastus mentioned, you want  to install the JSON parser `jq` first. After that, it's just a matter of filtering for the value you want.

I should mention that the JSON block you posted isn't valid; the opening bracket of "items" isn't closed, and the second entry in `items` should have a comma separator. Despite that, I'm going to assume you have a valid block, and only cut-and-pasted what you thought was relevant. If each block is indeed representative, then all you should need to add is (assuming `bash` is your shell)

```
echo "${YOUR_JSON_BLOCK}"  |  jq '.items[].hostRef.hostId'
```

This will output just those lines, as specified, assuming YOUR_JSON_BLOCK is the full valid json string with your data.

Answer (score 1):

`jq` has already been mentioned a few times, so i'll mention `jsonpipe`.  It converts `json` data to a line-oriented format suitable for processing with command tools like `grep`, `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, etc.  It's both a command-line tool for working with `json` in a shell, and a python library.

For example, if your sample json data is saved to a file called `alex.json`, and then edited so that it's actually valid json:

```
$ jsonpipe < alex.json 
/   {}
/items  []
/items/0    {}
/items/0/name   "first-block-e70a2fe8fd0531ad1f87de49f03537a6"
/items/0/type   "STORE"
/items/0/hostRef    {}
/items/0/hostRef/hostId "166219e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ce32"
/items/0/roleState  "STARTED"
/items/0/healthSummary  "GOOD"
/items/1    {}
/items/1/name   "second-block-c21a1ae8dd2831cd1b87de49f98274e8"
/items/1/type   "STORE"
/items/1/hostRef    {}
/items/1/hostRef/hostId "176429e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ad63"
/items/1/roleState  "STARTED"
/items/1/healthSummary  "GOOD"
/items/2    {}
/items/2/name   "first-block-a85d2fe6fd0482ad1f54de49f45174a0"
/items/2/type   "STORE"
/items/2/hostRef    {}
/items/2/hostRef/hostId "176429e3-ae1d-46d0-b4c7-66123a24fa82"
/items/2/roleState  "STARTED"
/items/2/healthSummary  "GOOD"
```

You could then pipe it into awk to extract anything that looks like a  hostId in the 2nd field of the range beginning with the pattern /first-block/ and ending with /hostId/.

```
$ jsonpipe < alex.json  | 
    awk '/first-block/,/hostId/ {
             if ($2 ~ /\"[a-f0-9]{8}-/) {
                 gsub(/\"/,"",$2);
                 print $2
             }
         }'
166219e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ce32
176429e3-ae1d-46d0-b4c7-66123a24fa82
```

BTW, You can get `jsonpipe` output in "paragraph" format, with each "item" in a separate paragraph, by piping it into `sed`.   e.g. in this case, add a newline before every item record.

```
$ jsonpipe < alex.json | 
    sed -e 's/\/items\/[[:digit:]]\+[[:blank:]]\+/\n&/'
/   {}
/items  []

/items/0    {}
/items/0/name   "first-block-e70a2fe8fd0531ad1f87de49f03537a6"
/items/0/type   "STORE"
/items/0/hostRef    {}
/items/0/hostRef/hostId "166219e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ce32"
/items/0/roleState  "STARTED"
/items/0/healthSummary  "GOOD"

/items/1    {}
/items/1/name   "second-block-c21a1ae8dd2831cd1b87de49f98274e8"
/items/1/type   "STORE"
/items/1/hostRef    {}
/items/1/hostRef/hostId "176429e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ad63"
/items/1/roleState  "STARTED"
/items/1/healthSummary  "GOOD"

/items/2    {}
/items/2/name   "first-block-a85d2fe6fd0482ad1f54de49f45174a0"
/items/2/type   "STORE"
/items/2/hostRef    {}
/items/2/hostRef/hostId "176429e3-ae1d-46d0-b4c7-66123a24fa82"
/items/2/roleState  "STARTED"
/items/2/healthSummary  "GOOD"
```

Paragraph-separated data is a very common format, and common tools like `awk` and `sed` and `perl`<sup>1</sup> have features that make it easy to work with paragraphs.  Also, there are many examples of such work easily found on this and other SE sites, as well as with google.

Finally, `jsonpipe` has a `jsonunpipe` counterpart to convert this line-oriented flat format back to json.

For example, if you wanted to flatten the structure so that hostId was a property of an item itself rather than in hostRef:

```
$ jsonpipe < alex.json  | 
      sed -e '/hostRef[[:blank:]]/d;s/hostRef\///' |
      jsonunpipe
{"items": [{"name": "first-block-e70a2fe8fd0531ad1f87de49f03537a6", "type": "STORE", "hostId": "166219e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ce32", "roleState": "STARTED", "healthSummary": "GOOD"}, {"name": "second-block-c21a1ae8dd2831cd1b87de49f98274e8", "type": "STORE", "hostId": "176429e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ad63", "roleState": "STARTED", "healthSummary": "GOOD"}, {"name": "first-block-a85d2fe6fd0482ad1f54de49f45174a0", "type": "STORE", "hostId": "176429e3-ae1d-46d0-b4c7-66123a24fa82", "roleState": "STARTED", "healthSummary": "GOOD"}]}
```

If required, you could then pipe that through `jq` or `json_pp` or similar to pretty-print it for human readability.

---

<sup>1</sup> `perl` has several excellent modules for parsing and manipulating json data, so you're probably better off using one of them.  Whenever you find yourself piping data from `grep`, `sed` and/or `awk` into `perl`, you really should ask yourself "Why am I doing this?  That's crazy, I should just do the whole thing in perl".  The same can be said for `python`.

Answer (score 0):

recently I have came up with an easier unix/shell alternative (it's entirely FOSS and free) to deal with json queries like that - take a look at *[`jtc`](https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc)*. The tool let handle relative walks (i.e. finding one and then offsetting to another).

assuming your original json is fixed (it has a couple of issues), then cli would be like this:

```
bash $ cat file.json | jtc -w'[name]:<^first-block>R: [-1] [hostRef] [hostId]'
"166219e3-be5c-46d0-b4c7-33543a29ce32"
"176429e3-ae1d-46d0-b4c7-66123a24fa82"
bash $
```

Answer (score 0):

[Another jq approach]
If you use [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) this is literally a one liner!

`cat input.json | jq -r '.["items"] | map(select(.name | contains("first-block"))) | .[].hostRef.hostId'`

P.S.

1. jq commands are pretty self explanatory, therefore I am not making an effort to explain it still if someone is facing difficulty let me know in comments, i will explain!
2. The json provided in the question is not complete!